# gralloc_goldfish(634): Emulator without GPU emulation detected

Tags: android, android-emulator, android-4.0-ice-cream-sandwich

I am using android SDK 4.0.3 and I'm trying to run a simple program in which I'm trying to switch from one page to another page using an Intent (By passing intent object as: Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(),SecondActivity.class);
startActivity(intent); )

[Also, I have 3GB RAM]

but when I run the program it gives something like this in DDMS:

```
01-23 01:58:23.892: D/gralloc_goldfish(634): Emulator without GPU emulation detected.

01-23 01:58:45.482: D/AndroidRuntime(634): Shutting down VM

01-23 01:58:45.492: W/dalvikvm(634): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x409c01f8)

01-23 01:58:45.532: E/AndroidRuntime(634): FATAL EXCEPTION: main

01-23 01:58:45.532: E/AndroidRuntime(634): android.content.ActivityNotFoundException: 
Unable to find explicit activity class {com.example.actionbar_demo/com.example.actionbar_demo.SecondActivity}; have you declared this activity in your AndroidManifest.xml?

01-23 01:58:45.532: E/AndroidRuntime(634):  at android.app.Instrumentation.checkStartActivityResult(Instrumentation.java:1508)

01-23 01:58:45.532: E/AndroidRuntime(634):  at android.app.Instrumentation.execStartActivity(Instrumentation.java:1384)

01-23 01:58:45.532: E/AndroidRuntime(634):  at android.app.Activity.startActivityForResult(Activity.java:3190)

01-23 01:58:45.532: E/AndroidRuntime(634):  at com.example.actionbar_demo.Actionbar_demoActivity$1.onClick(Actionbar_demoActivity.java:23)

01-23 01:58:45.532: E/AndroidRuntime(634):  at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:3511)

01-23 01:58:45.532: E/AndroidRuntime(634):  at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:14105)

01-23 01:58:45.532: E/AndroidRuntime(634):  at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:605)

01-23 01:58:45.532: E/AndroidRuntime(634):  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)

01-23 01:58:45.532: E/AndroidRuntime(634):  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)

01-23 01:58:45.532: E/AndroidRuntime(634):  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4424)

01-23 01:58:45.532: E/AndroidRuntime(634):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)

01-23 01:58:45.532: E/AndroidRuntime(634):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)

01-23 01:58:45.532: E/AndroidRuntime(634):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:784)

01-23 01:58:45.532: E/AndroidRuntime(634):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:551)

01-23 01:58:45.532: E/AndroidRuntime(634):  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)

01-23 01:58:49.173: I/Process(634): Sending signal. PID: 634 SIG: 9
```

Answer (score 8):

If you're worried about the:

```
Emulator without GPU emulation detected.
```

I wouldn't be. Given that a cursory search of the net turns it up quite a bit, and it's not related to the specific problems being discussed, I'd say it's just an indication that your emulator simply doesn't emulate the GPU. It's unlikely to be a problem.

That's supported by the fact it's a *debug* message (not even a warning, let alone an error) and also that there's a big 42-second gap between that and your actual problem.

The *actual* problem seems to be indicated by the line:

```
01-23 01:58:45.532: E/AndroidRuntime(634):
    android.content.ActivityNotFoundException: Unable to find explicit activity
    class {com.example.actionbar_demo/com.example.actionbar_demo.SecondActivity};
    have you declared this activity in your AndroidManifest.xml?
```

So I have to ask: *have* you declared this activity in your AndroidManifest.xml?