# Android - HttpResponse and the codes after that don't run

Tags: android, json

My problem is: in my code, I am trying to get JSON objects from an HTTP client and print them in LogCat. But there was nothing happening. So **for testing, I added Log("sdf","1") lines.** Now I can see that **after Log("sdf","2") line, no code is running**. There is no error, no exception or no something like that. I have added the Internet permission. Am I missing something or does my Eclipse have some problems? Thanks for the help.

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    DefaultHttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient(new BasicHttpParams());
    HttpGet httpget = new HttpGet("http://tusyad2014.org/akb_api/hastalarimiza_ozel.json");
    httpget.setHeader("Content-type", "application/json;charset=utf-8");

    Log.e("sdf","1");
    try {
        Log.e("sdf","2");
        HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httpget);
        Log.e("sdf","3");
        String result = EntityUtils.toString(response.getEntity(), "UTF-8");
        Log.e("sdf","4");
        JSONArray ja = new JSONArray(result);

        Log.e("sdf","5");

        int n = ja.length();

        for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {

          JSONObject jo = ja.getJSONObject(i);

          Log.d("sdf","Json : " + jo.getString("id") + " - "+ jo.getString("name"));

        }

    } catch (Exception e) {

      Log.e("sdf","");
    }      
}   
}
```

### LOG

```
08-15 05:14:40.609: E/sdf(1656): 1
08-15 05:14:40.609: E/sdf(1656): 2
08-15 05:14:41.167: D/gralloc_goldfish(1656): Emulator without GPU emulation detected.
```

Comment: You should not make HTTP requests on the main thread, use a separate thread (e.g. AsyncTask).

Comment: You should use Thread or AsyncTask for this operations in background..

Comment: I used Runnable first. There was no change. Was it wrong?

Comment: You should use Thread with Handler.

Comment: 1.5 yıl sonra gelen edit için teşekkürler amın oğlu.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As Raghunandan suggest you need to use `Asynctask` or Background Thread for this operations.

For Example :

```
    new AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void>() {


    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
                        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                        super.onPreExecute();
    Log.i("onPreExecute","onPreExecute");
                    }


@Override
protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {

DefaultHttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient(new BasicHttpParams());
    HttpGet httpget = new HttpGet("http://tusyad2014.org/akb_api/hastalarimiza_ozel.json");
    httpget.setHeader("Content-type", "application/json;charset=utf-8");

    Log.e("sdf","1");
    try {
        Log.e("sdf","2");
        HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httpget);
        Log.e("sdf","3");
        String result = EntityUtils.toString(response.getEntity(), "UTF-8");
        Log.e("sdf","4");
        JSONArray ja = new JSONArray(result);

        Log.e("sdf","5");

        int n = ja.length();

        for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {

          JSONObject jo = ja.getJSONObject(i);

          Log.d("sdf","Json : " + jo.getString("id") + " - "+ jo.getString("name"));

        }

    } catch (Exception e) {

      Log.e("sdf","");
    }      


}       
    }.execute();
```

EDIT :

And also see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8968348/1405983).

Comment: @ArdaOğulÜçpınar You are welcome brother. Happy codding and glad to help you.

Answer (score 1):

You are running network related operation on the ui thread which is not possible. Use a `Thread` or `Asynctask`.

Post Honeycomb you will get `NetworkOnMainThreadException`

> This is only thrown for applications targeting the Honeycomb SDK or
>   higher. Applications targeting earlier SDK versions are allowed to do
>   networking on their main event loop threads, but it's heavily
>   discouraged. See the document Designing for Responsiveness.

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/NetworkOnMainThreadException.html

AsyncTask docs

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html

Edit

```
 new TheTask().execute();
```

Then

```
public void  getJson()
  {
        HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
        httpclient.getParams().setParameter(CoreProtocolPNames.PROTOCOL_VERSION, HttpVersion.HTTP_1_1);
        HttpGet request = new HttpGet("http://tusyad2014.org/akb_api/hastalarimiza_ozel.json");     
        try
        {
        HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(request);
        HttpEntity resEntity = response.getEntity();
        String _response=EntityUtils.toString(resEntity);
        Log.e("sdf",_response);

        } catch (Exception e) {

          Log.e("sdf","");
        }      
    }   
    class TheTask extends AsyncTask <String,Void,Void>
  { 
    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        super.onPreExecute();
    }
    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Void result) {

    super.onPostExecute(result);

    }
    @Override
    protected Void doInBackground(String... params) {
        getJson();
        return null;
    }
    }   
  }
```

Log

```
08-15 15:05:26.745: E/sdf(21197): [{"id":"1","name":"Ayakta Åekil BozukluÄu- Kemik ÃÄ±kÄ±ntÄ±sÄ±- Halluks Valgus - Halluks Rijitus"},{"id":"2","name":"ÃekiÃ§ Parmak"},{"id":"3","name":"DoÄumsal El, Ayak, Ãst Ekstremite Anamolileri, Eksiklikleri, Åekil BozukluklarÄ±"},{"id":"4","name":"DoÄum Felci- DoÄum sonrasÄ± Beyin Felci, Spastisite"},{"id":"5","name":"KapalÄ± omuz, dirsek, el bileÄi ameliyatlarÄ±- ARTROSKOPÄ°K cerrahi giriÅimler"},{"id":"6","name":"Ortopedi de PRP ( trombositten zengin plazma) uygulamalarÄ±"},{"id":"7","name":"KÄ±rÄ±k kaynama gecikmesi, kaynamamalarÄ± ve ultrason tedavisi"},{"id":"8","name":"El bileÄi kÄ±rÄ±klarÄ±, radius ve ulna alt uÃ§ kÄ±rÄ±klarÄ±, skafoid kÄ±rÄ±klarÄ±"},{"id":"9","name":"Humerus kÄ±rÄ±klarÄ±, radial sinir sorunlarÄ±, kaynamamalarÄ±"},{"id":"10","name":"Eldeki kistler,Ganglion kistleri"},{"id":"11","name":"Dirsek aÄrÄ±sÄ±,TenisÃ§i dirseÄi, GolfÃ§Ã¼ dirseÄi"},{"id":"12","name":"Elde uyuÅma, karÄ±ncalanma, iÄnelenme, aÄrÄ±"},{"id":"13","name":"Pleksus ve sinir yaralanmalarÄ±"},{"id":"14","name":"Ãnkol Kemik (Radius ve Ulna) KaynamamalarÄ±"},{"id":"15","name":"Femur BaÅÄ± AvaskÃ¼ler Nekrozu"},{"id":"16","name":"Tetik Parmak"},{"id":"17","name":"BaÅparmak TendonlarÄ±nÄ±n SÄ±kÄ±ÅmasÄ± (De Quervain HastalÄ±ÄÄ±)"},{"id":"18","name":"Omuz AÄrÄ±sÄ± ve Hareket KÄ±sÄ±tlÄ±lÄ±ÄÄ±"},{"id":"19","name":"DoÄumsal Tibia KaynamamasÄ± (Konjenital Tibia PsÃ¶doartrozu)"}]
```

Comment: I will add LogCat output. I know in this case I should get NetworkOnMainThreadException but no; I dont.

Comment: @ArdaOğulÜçpınar updated code. i checked i do get the json now

Answer (score 0):

The problem might be that your network is slow...... it takes a while to get response in slow connection....

further it would be giving exception in new android apis as you are doing network related work on main thread

Comment: I have 19.54Mbit internet speed and less than 1ms ping.

Comment: and what about your webservice .... I remember when I was doing it from a webservice which had more 3000 json entries it took a while...

Comment: Just few entries. less than 20

Comment: try using async task or background thread... ultimately you have to use it after post honey comb as suggested above..

Comment: Yeah. Done with async.

Comment: ok.... put a breakpoint before HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httpget);and see where its going using debugger